# Calculating NDDI in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to compute the Normalized Difference Drought Index (NDDI) using the following formula:
(NDVI - NDWI) / (NDVI + NDWI). I tried the following:

```
// cloudmask for TOA data
var toa = function(image) {
 var qa = image.select('BQA');
 var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).eq(0);
 return image.updateMask(mask);
};

// cloudmask for SR data
var sr = function(image) {
 var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
 var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3)
   .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5))
 return image.updateMask(mask.not());
};


var sowSeason = function (collection) {
 return collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2013, 2021, 'year'))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10, 12, 'month'))
};



var COLLECTION = ee.Dictionary({
 'L4': {
   'TOA': ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_TOA'),
   'SR': ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_SR'),
   'TIR': ['B6',]
 },
 'L5': {
   'TOA': ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA'),
   'SR': ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR'),
   'TIR': ['B6',]
 },
 'L7': {
   'TOA': ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA'),
   'SR': ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR'),
   'TIR': ['B6_VCID_1','B6_VCID_2'],
 },
 'L8': {
   'TOA': ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA'),
   'SR': ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR'),
   'TIR': ['B10','B11']
 }
});



var sowCol = function(landsat, geometry, use_ndvi) {

 // load TOA Radiance/Reflectance
 var collection_dict = ee.Dictionary(COLLECTION.get(landsat));

 var landsatTOA = ee.ImageCollection(collection_dict.get('TOA'))
                    .filterBounds(geometry)
                    .map(toa);
               
             
 // load Surface Reflectance collection for NDVI
 var landsatSR = ee.ImageCollection(collection_dict.get('SR'))
               .filterBounds(geometry)
               .map(sr)

 // combine collections
 // all channels from surface reflectance collection
 // except tir channels: from TOA collection
 // select TIR bands
 var tir = ee.List(collection_dict.get('TIR'));
 var landsatALL = sowSeason(landsatSR).combine(sowSeason(landsatTOA.select(tir)), true);
 
 return landsatALL;
};


var satellite = 'L8';
var use_ndvi = false;
var LandsatSowCol = sowCol(satellite, Zambia, use_ndvi)



var addNDVI = function(image) {
 //NDVI = (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)
 var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
 return image.addBands(ndvi)
             .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
};


var addNDWI = function(image) {
 //NDWI = (Green - NIR) / (Green + NIR )
 var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']).rename('NDWI');
 return image.addBands(ndwi)
             .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
};

var addNDDI = function(image) {
 //NDDI = (NDVI - NDWI) / (NDVI + NDWI)
 var nddi = image.normalizedDifference(['NDVI', 'NDWI']).rename('NDDI');
 return image.addBands(nddi)
             .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
};


var newCol = LandsatSowCol.map(addNDVI)
                         .map(addNDWI)
                         .map(addNDDI).select(['NDVI', 'NDWI', 'NDDI'])



var years = ee.List.sequence(2013, 2021);
var sowingMonths = ee.List.sequence(10, 12);
var growingMonths = ee.List.sequence(1, 4);


// Map over the years and create a monthly average collection for the sowing season
var monthly_Sowing_Avg = function (sowCol){
 return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
   years.map(function(year) {
     return sowingMonths.map(function(month) {
       return sowCol
       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
       .mean()
       .set({'month': month, 'year': year});
 });
}).flatten())}



var monthlyCol = monthly_Sowing_Avg(newCol)
var NDDI_Oct2013  = monthlyCol.first().select('NDDI')
var nddiParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['green', 'yellow', 'red']};
Map.addLayer(NDDI_Oct2013.clip(Zambia), nddiParams, 'NDDI Oct 2013');
```

When I display the final results (NDDI image) it's empty. I am not sure what's the problem.

Comment: Please provide a code sample which can be run to reproduce the problem (without using any modules, like the link does). There isn't anything visibly wrong with the code you have supplied in the question.

Comment: I added a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following and it seems to produce actual images. I am not sure if the resultant images are "correct" or not though.

```
var addNDDI = function(image) {
 //NDDI = (NDVI - NDWI) / (NDVI + NDWI)
 var nddi = image.expression(
 '(((B5 - B4) / (B5 + B4)) - ((B3 - B5) / (B3 + B5))) / (((B5 - B4) / (B5 + B4)) + ((B3 - B5) / (B3 + B5)))',{
 'B3'  : image.select('B3'),
 'B5'  : image.select('B5'),
 'B4'  : image.select('B4')});
 return image.addBands(nddi.rename('NDDI'))
             .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
};
```

Or

```
var addNDDI = function(image) {
 //NDDI = (NDVI - NDWI) / (NDVI + NDWI)
 var nddi = image.expression(
 '(NDVI - NDWI) / (NDVI + NDWI)',{
 'NDVI'  : image.select('NDVI'),
 'NDWI' : image.select('NDWI')});
 return image.addBands(nddi.rename('NDDI'))
             .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
};
```